# Repository Constructor not working

Tags: api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a asp.net core project using Entity framework core and restful API.

Below is my code :

Startup.cs :

```
 services.AddTransient<ISupplierRepository, SupplierRepository>();
```

SuppliersController.cs :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SuppliersController : Controller
{
    private ISupplierRepository _iSupplierRepository;

    public SuppliersController(ISupplierRepository iSupplierRepository)
    {
        _iSupplierRepository = iSupplierRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetSupplier()
    {
        try
        {
            var suppliers= _iSupplierRepository.Gets();
            return Ok(suppliers);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

ISupplierRepository,cs :

```
public interface ISupplierRepository
{
    List<Supplier> Gets();
}
```

SupplierRepository.cs :

```
public class SupplierRepository : ISupplierRepository
{
    private static InventoryDbContext _context;

    public SupplierRepository(InventoryDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Supplier> Gets()
    {
        return _context.Suppliers.ToList();
    }
 }
```

My problem is when I call api http://localhost:53775/api/suppliers then it working find when I remove constructor part of "SupplierRepository.cs". But when I want to call that api with SupplierRepository.cs constructor then directly showing 500 internal server error (also in console). Actual error not showing. I unable to find the problem. Why this error showing.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add DbContext as well.

```
var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

This will inject the InventoryDbContext to the controller.